# Why am I getting this KeyError?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to write a function that uses Python Dictionary to compute the scrabble score of an English word. I'm almost there but I keep getting the annoying error:

Here's the code:

```
d = {"0":'blank',
     "1":'A, E, I, L, N, O, R, S, T, U',
     "2":'D, G',
     "3":'B, C, M, P',
     "4":'F, H, V, W, Y',
     "5":'K',
     "8":'J, X',
     "10":'Q, Z',}


w = input("enter a word")

def scrab(w):  #define function
    tot = 0
    w.upper()
    for key in w:
       tot = tot + d[key]

    return tot




scrab(w)

print(tot, w)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bola42/Downloads/IsaiahSLab13Dictionary.py", line 65, in <module>
    scrab(w)
  File "C:/Users/Bola42/Downloads/IsaiahSLab13Dictionary.py", line 58, in scrab
    tot = tot + d[key]
KeyError: ' '
```

Help with this? What is going on?

Comment: let us know what input gave the errror? Also 'scrab' function isn't clear ? Could you elaborate more why u need a loop there.

Comment: Be more descriptive in the title, write a title that summarizes the specific problem.
Also a better introduction to the problem and minimal example would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the keys and values backward. You are using the scores as keys in your dictionary and strings of letters as the values. In addition you are not using `strip()` on the input value, so you are processing incidental whitespace instead of alphabetical characters alone.

Answer (score 0):

You have a dict of String to String. It would be better to create a map like String/Character to an integer value like below. I am using your dict `d` for the same for simplicity:

```
wmap = {}
for key, val in d.items():
    for val in val.split(", "):
        newKey = val.strip()
        wmap[newKey] = int(key)
```

this would create the below:

```
{'blank': 0,
 'A': 1,
 'E': 1,
 'I': 1,
 'L': 1,
 'N': 1,
 'O': 1,
 'R': 1,
 'S': 1,
 'T': 1,
 'U': 1,
 'D': 2,
 'G': 2,
 'B': 3,
 'C': 3,
 'M': 3,
 'P': 3,
 'F': 4,
 'H': 4,
 'V': 4,
 'W': 4,
 'Y': 4,
 'K': 5,
 'J': 8,
 'X': 8,
 'Q': 10,
 'Z': 10}
```

Update `scrab()` as below:

```
def scrab(w):  
    tot = 0
    w = w.upper()
    for key in w:
        print(key)
        tot = tot + wmap[str(key)]

    return tot
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to look for a whitespace as a dictionary key. 
Sanitize and `strip` whitespaces from the user's input.

---

There's another problem; You're iterating throw a string and looking for each letter in the dictionary keys. But your dictionary has numeric keys.
Try with a dictionary in this form:

```py
SCRABBLE_LETTERS_VALUE = {
    "A": 1,
    "B": 3,
    "C": 3,
    "D": 2,
    "E": 1,
    "F": 4,
    "G": 2,
    "H": 4,
    "I": 1,
    "J": 8,
    "K": 5,
    "L": 1,
    "M": 3,
    "N": 1,
    "O": 1,
    "P": 3,
    "Q": 10,
    "R": 1,
    "S": 1,
    "T": 1,
    "U": 1,
    "V": 4,
    "W": 4,
    "X": 8,
    "Y": 4,
    "Z": 10,
}
```